# Concatenate 2 line with same pattern while build printing in columns

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with thousands of lines and i am trying to print them in a order. My file has something like below

```
<EMP>78</EMP>
<Time>2020-12-01T05:07:07</Time>
  <ArrayLocationID>AB</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>833</EMP>
<Time>2020-12-01T05:09:31</Time>
  <ArrayLocationID>PW</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>133</EMP>
<Time>2020-12-01T05:22:15</Time>
  <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>3109</EMP>
<Time>2020-12-01T05:27:54</Time>
  <ArrayLocationID>AW</ArrayLocationID>
  <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>153</EMP>
<Time>2020-12-01T05:29:12</Time>
<ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>
```

I want them to look like below

```
<EMP>78</EMP>           <Time>2020-12-01T05:07:07</Time>          <ArrayLocationID>AB</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>833</EMP>          <Time>2020-12-01T05:09:31</Time>          <ArrayLocationID>PW</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>133</EMP>          <Time>2020-12-01T05:22:15</Time>          <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>3109</EMP>         <Time>2020-12-01T05:27:54</Time>          <ArrayLocationID>AW</ArrayLocationID>   <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>     
<EMP>153</EMP>          <Time>2020-12-01T05:29:12</Time>          <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>
```

I used grep to find a pattern and then printed next 3 lines so that i can format them using paste option which is `grep -A3 EMP sampleFile | paste - - -`

but i got below

```
    <EMP>78</EMP>           <Time>2020-12-01T05:07:07</Time>          <ArrayLocationID>AB</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>833</EMP>          <Time>2020-12-01T05:09:31</Time>          <ArrayLocationID>PW</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>133</EMP>          <Time>2020-12-01T05:22:15</Time>          <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>3109</EMP>         <Time>2020-12-01T05:27:54</Time>          <ArrayLocationID>AW</ArrayLocationID>
      <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>     <EMP>153</EMP>          <Time>2020-12-01T05:29:12</Time>
  <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>
```

If there are multiple ArrayLocationID tags how can i print them on the same line? My file always starts with EMP tag. Any help is appropriated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file | sed 's/<EMP>/\n&/g; s/  */\t/g' | sed '1d; $s/$/\n/'
```

Output:

```
<EMP>78</EMP>   <Time>2020-12-01T05:07:07</Time>        <ArrayLocationID>AB</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>833</EMP>  <Time>2020-12-01T05:09:31</Time>        <ArrayLocationID>PW</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>133</EMP>  <Time>2020-12-01T05:22:15</Time>        <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>3109</EMP> <Time>2020-12-01T05:27:54</Time>        <ArrayLocationID>AW</ArrayLocationID>   <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>153</EMP>  <Time>2020-12-01T05:29:12</Time>        <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `awk` quite easily with the following:

```
awk '
    /^<EMP>/ { printf (FNR>1?"\n%s":"%s"), $1; next }
             { printf "\t%s", $1 }
    END      { print "" }
' file
```

Or if you wanted it all in one line:

```
awk '/^<EMP>/{printf(FNR>1?"\n%s":"%s"),$1;next} {printf"\t%s",$1} END{print ""}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
<EMP>78</EMP>   <Time>2020-12-01T05:07:07</Time>        <ArrayLocationID>AB</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>833</EMP>  <Time>2020-12-01T05:09:31</Time>        <ArrayLocationID>PW</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>133</EMP>  <Time>2020-12-01T05:22:15</Time>        <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>3109</EMP> <Time>2020-12-01T05:27:54</Time>        <ArrayLocationID>AW</ArrayLocationID>   <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>153</EMP>  <Time>2020-12-01T05:29:12</Time>        <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>
```

Or to more closely match your output, you could change the first rule to apply padding after the first field using a `printf` *field-width* modifier using a second `"%*s"` with an empty string `""`, e.g.

```
/^<EMP>/{printf(FNR>1?"\n%s%*s":"%s%*s"),$1,length($1)%8,"";next}
```

**Example Output**

With the padding, the output becomes:

```
<EMP>78</EMP>           <Time>2020-12-01T05:07:07</Time>        <ArrayLocationID>AB</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>833</EMP>          <Time>2020-12-01T05:09:31</Time>        <ArrayLocationID>PW</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>133</EMP>          <Time>2020-12-01T05:22:15</Time>        <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>3109</EMP>         <Time>2020-12-01T05:27:54</Time>        <ArrayLocationID>AW</ArrayLocationID>   <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>
<EMP>153</EMP>          <Time>2020-12-01T05:29:12</Time>        <ArrayLocationID>BE</ArrayLocationID>
```